# Probability of sampling >50% "bright" pixels from an image

Tags: probability, image-processing, image-segmentation

Suppose an image consists of 300,000 pixels. 51% of these pixels are bright and 49% are dark. We are trying to determine if the image is bright or dark through sampling (in this example it would be bright since there are more bright pixels). If sampled 100 pixels without replacement, what would be the probability of success of classifying the image correctly as bright? We would need more than 50% of the samples to come up as bright to correctly classify the image.

Comment: It's not much greater than 50% (very close to 54%).  You would need to sample over 6800 pixels to have at least a 95% chance of being correct.  If this really is your situation (limited to 100 pixels), then the prognosis is not good.  But usually you can obtain better information by studying the relationships among all three quantities (%bright, sample size, and chance of being correct) so you can make appropriate trade-offs among your needs.

Comment: Yes, obviously I knew that the success rate is low. I was asking more for the method I would use to go about calculating this. I need to show proof of theoretical probability calculation and am a bit rusty on my college probability haha.

Comment: @whuber ^^ if you could help me that would be great!

Comment: This question, albeit with different numerical values, has been asked and answered many times here.  Search for questions about [binomial sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+sample+size) or [hypergeometric sample size](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hypergeometric+sample+size). Both are applicable. In fact, you can safely use [standard Normal approximations.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sample+size+normal)